"Error changing directory to '/' " error when trying to browse files on android via KDE connect via WINSCP
When attempting to browse phone files on Android through Windows 11 using KDE Connect with the assistance of WinSCP, selecting the 'browse device' option launches WinSCP, which then presents the following error.


I have found a solution for this error, perhaps someone can modify the script itself, so this workaround need not be done

simple Workaround is
In the address tab

change it to
/storage/emulated/0
to access internal storage
and
/storage/1234-1234/  (replace 1234 for your device specific memory card directory) for memory card.
from the workaround its fairly obvious that winscp script is trying access Root directory, which is not allowed by the phone and it needs to be changed everytime you use feature.
